# Downloading an image from wallofcelebrities.com

Tags: copyright, internet, photography

Is [Wallofcelebrities](https://www.wallofcelebrities.com/) a legal place to download images from?

I would like to get one of Kayla Compton, but I'm not sure if these photos are being illegally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the image. If the person who created it, or who holds the copyright, or a license to distribute the image, uploaded it with the intent that others should be able to download it, then it is legal to do so.

On the other hand if the person who uploaded it was not authorized to do so, and had no rights to the image in the first place, then the uploader could not validly grant any rights to anyone, because the uploader had no rights to grant (you can't sell what you don't own). In that case simply downloading would be a copyright infringement, although the copyright holder might well not try to sue people who downloaded the image for personal use believing in good faith that the upload was authorized.

Evn if the upload was authorized, it may noit have authorized anyone to make additional copies, to modify the image, or to pass copies along to others. Unless, of course, the image was posted with a license that grants those permissions.

The site on which an image is posted really makes very little difference, except that the site's reputation. If the image is posted on "Copyvios-R-us" one might not trust any assurances that it is legal without checking. If it is posted on "SterlingSite" one might more reasonably trust any claims as to authorization and rights granted. But the question always is, was the person who uploaded the image the copyright holder, or authorized by the holder, and what rights, if any,  are granted to possible re-users.  Note that if an image is posted with no license statement and no mention of any grant of rights, one should treat that as "all rights reserved". Posting by an authorized person allows amnyone to view it lawfully, and possibly to download a copy for personal off-line viewing, but nothing more unless more is explicitly granted.

Comment: May I just send you the link of the image if that's legal to? So you get a better idea

Comment: And i am only using it for personal viewing on my computers nothing more I promise

Comment: And i don't know who or what uploaded it and I don't know ifor he was authorized

Comment: @Justan The chance of anyone suing you for personally viewing an image posted by someone else is very small if you never redistribute or modify the image. But if you wanted to redistribute or create a modified version, the copyright issue would be much more significant. I can't tell from the link any more than you can - I'd have to do research into the image, which i'm not going to do. This not knowing is a major problem with works, especially images, posted to the net.

Comment: Well the image IS from a movie btw

Comment: Is there such thing of an app for android that blocks someone from downloading illegal stuff like what the new iphone has so you do not have to worry about getting in trouble with the law

Comment: @Justin, In that case, the copyright is almost surely owned by the production company that made the movie (or its successor) and anyone not at least claiming to be acting for that company is pretty obviously not authorized. (unless the movie is old enoiugh that its copyright has lapsed, which is possible but unlikely)

Comment: @Justin i don't know of any app which claims to do that, but there aere tons of apps out there I don't know of. I don't see how an app could reliably make a determination of what is under copyright, much less what might be available under fair use. I think any app claiming to do that would not be reliable, it would either under block or over block, or perhaps both.